# Download images from web and use downloaded images when presen

Tags: c#

My C# program needs to display, of many possible images, one at a time. The images are on the web and I have a precise URL for each one. The program needs to either load the image from the web or, if it has been loaded previously, load it from memory/file (as the previous loading from the web should have saved it to memory/file). How do I implement this? I can get the loading from the web with a WebRequest object, but that's not enough to save it for later, faster, use.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(imageURL);
Stream stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
pictureBoxFirstPack.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you should be able to do this:

```
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 stream.CopyTo(ms);
 Byte[]  data = ms.ToArray();
```

Once you have it as a Byte array you can store it in a dictionary, a database, or wherever you like really.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Image.Save method to save the downloaded image (follow an example from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx)

```cs
// Construct a bitmap from the button image resource.
Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(typeof(Button), "Button.bmp");

// Save the image as a GIF.
bmp1.Save("c:\\button.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

One of the possible ways to check if the image already exists in your local storage is to calculate the hash-sum of every downloaded image and save it inside a dictionary

```
SHA256Managed sha = new SHA256Managed();
byte[] checksum = sha.ComputeHash(stream);
var hash = BitConverter.ToString(checksum).Replace("-", String.Empty);
// Store hash into a dictionary
```

Comment: This gave me a weird exception that I couldn't fix

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WebClient to download file like this:

```
string fileNameLocally = @"c:\file.jpg";
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
        client.DownloadFile(imageURL, fileNameLocally);
//you can also use DownloadAsyncFile this methods do not block the calling thread.
}
```

Comment: Something didn't work here, gave me a 'General' exception that I couldn't fix

Comment: Please copy/paste entire error message and the way you have implemented the code